# Finding Ages of Cousins from their multiplied value

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Today my three cousins multiplied their ages together and it came to
2016. This day last year their ages multiplied to 1377.
When they multiplied their ages together 2 years ago today, what was
their answer?

I have got the above problem

where I can derive up to

AxBxC = 2016

same day prev year it is AxBxC = 1377

I could say there are 36 months (12 months * 3 cousins) difference.

How to solve this one further. Thanks

Comment: It's $(A-1)(B-1)(C-1)=1377;$  prime factor 2016 and 1377.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $2016=2^5 \times 3^2 \times 7$ and $1377=3^4 \times 17$ so ..
\begin{eqnarray*}
ABC&=&4 \times 18 \times 28 \\
(A-1)(B-1)(C-1) &=&3 \times 17 \times 27 \\
(A-2)(B-2)(C-2) &=& 2 \times 16 \times 26= \color{red}{832}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: How did you get 4, 18, 28 for ABC

Comment: In the previous year one of the cousins must be $17,51,153,459$ or $1377$ years old ... add one to each of these to eliminate the last $4$ possibilities ... etc ...